# Evaluate $\int d(zx)+\int d(xy)=0$

Tags: integration

I'm not sure whether to say evaluate or solve. Should the result be something like,
$zx + xy + c(y,z) = 0$ or shall I ignore $c(y,z)$?

Comment: Definitely evaluate. As for your +C, think about doing this backwards. If you differentiated zx+xy+c(y,x) with respect to x what would you get?

Comment: @Daniel , thanks but shouldn't I differentiate the solution with respect to y and z in order to get $c'(y,z)$?

Comment: Correct, and then from the chain rule you know that this is zero if $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=0$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=0$. If only one of them is zero, you will have c(y) or c(z), and if both are zero you will have a regular old constant number.
I'd post this as an answer, but I've not actually done multi-variable calculus and so there might be something I'm missing. To the best of my knowledge, though, that's your answer.